# Hyperledger fabric for production on multiple AWS instance. And How to get the CA certificate for production

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have completed the tutorials of

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-index.
I can create the Application in my local system along with REST apis and Angular application. All the examples uses the fabric Network from some git repository. Those comes with predefined Org and peers.
I want to have my Own Organisations and peers defined and my own channel.

My Network will have 4 Organisations, each with 1 or 2 peers. I also want to deploy the complete system on multiple AWS EC2 instances.

Also need to know how to get the CA Root certificates for production environment,

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-index.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy fabric network over multiple was instances you can use docker and docker swarm which follows master and worker node architecture you can follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

to get root CA certificate you need to deploy root CA and then configure intermediate CA with root CA for this follow fabric CA docs https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/